# Displaying a list of 'projects'(folders) on website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I itentially did not list what language to use because i'm not sure whatt he best way to accomplish this is. I'm very new to HTML/CSS/JS/PHP and i'm building a portfolio website. I do have background in other languages which helps some-what to follow syntax.

Anyways, i'm trying to find the best way to list a directory of files for someone to sort of browse through. I have projects in multiple languages (Matlab, R, Labview, etc.) I was hoping to do this in such a way that if I added a folder for a new project, everything would just dynamically update so that I didn't have to go into the HTML and make a physical link every time I wanted to add a project. I'll tell you some of the things i've attempted/researched:

- **Adding RSS/Atom feed that get data from my Github master.atom page.** I think this is the best solution by far because then I only have to commit updates and the feed on my website would be updated dynamically. The problem i think is that I still have to provide the path to the master.atom pages for all projects in my HTML files, correct?
- **Use PHP to scan directory and return contents.** This is probably pretty easy and I think I might be over complicating it but what I've done is create an index page in my 'projects' path, i.e. 'root/projects/index.html'. The index scans the 'projects' directory using the following code that i sort of put together from different resources on stackoverflow,

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result === '.' or $result === '..' or $result === 'Images') continue;

    if (is_dir($path . '/' . $result)) {
        echo'
            <div id="'.$result.'">
            <a href="'.$result.'/" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" role="button">'.$result.'</a>
            </div>';
    }  
} ?>
```

and then with the buttons this code created I would call a javascript script that would get the ID of the button clicked and show it's sub directory files associated with it in another  element on the current page, i.e., User clicks a button labelled 'Matlab' and another scan scans the folders in in Matlab folder and then shows the folders scanned in another div element on the current projects page.

I know this is a very crude way to implement this but i'm at a point where I just want to get something up and then mess with optimization later.

Comment: I think you have a solution already. What do you need from us?

Comment: Why not just use your GutHub profile? Just seems to be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Halcyon I suppose I was just looking for what the "best" method to achieve this is. I know what i want in my head, but because i'm new to all of this, I don't really know the best/most effective way to handle this.

Comment: @nerdlyist I had a lot of trouble setting up Github to direct to my own domain and on top of that, I can't find (read: I'm likely asking the wrong questions) documentation on how to link to things in a github page. I know it's a lot more involved but i'm just trying to create my webpage dynamically so I only have to update ONE location.

Comment: My idea was to not have your own site and just used GitHub as a profile. However have you looked here https://developer.github.com/v3/ it is the API and should be able to help. You can use whatever language you want really.